# Improper nesting of variable scopes in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, raii, scoping

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
ComplexObject cpy;
{
  RAIILockObject _(obj->mutex);
  cpy = obj->org;
}
// use cpy
```

For the sake of argument, assume the default constructor for `ComplexObject` is costly.

- Can (and do) C++ compilers replace the default construction/assignment of cpy with a copy constructor?
- Is there any way to restructure the code so as to *force* that optimization while preserving the scope of both local objects?

---

Edit: I'm really looking for a general solution to the issue of wanting improper nesting of RAII objects with other things.

Any comments on this take on [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764787/improper-nesting-of-variable-scopes-in-c/6765033#6765033)'s solution?

```
ComplexObject = LockedInitInPlace(obj->org, obj->mutex);

template<class C> C LockedInitInPlace(C& c, Mutex& m) {
    RAIILockObject _(m);
    return c;
}
```

---

Edit 2:

The origonal code has this sequence:

1. Default construct `cpy`
2. construct RAII `lock`
3. assign (copy) existing object to `cpy`
4. destruct `lock`
5. use `cpy`
6. destruct `cpy`

What I want is:

1. construct RAII `lock`
2. construct `cpy` (in this case by copy constructor using existing object).
3. destruct `lock`
4. use `cpy`
5. destruct `cpy`

Comment: Damn, I just realised that my solution won’t work if the copying itself is critical. And if it isn’t (please clarify!) then your code makes no sense.

Comment: @Konrad: For the type of cases I'm looking at, the default-constructor/assignment-operator pair would be the same as a copy-constructor so your solution is valid. However, I'm interested in the case where, while that is true, the compiler doesn't actually know it.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the compiler can prove to itself that such optimization results in the same behavior then no. I can't really imagine a case where (given the mutex lock) the compiler could do this.

This may sound obvious, but can you change the default constructor to *not* be costly? Such constructors are likely to cause performance problems in other places if they're easily to accidentally invoke.

Alternately you're going to have to use the heap and pointers (via copy construct creation) rather than local instances.

```
std::scoped_ptr<ComplexObject> cpyPtr = 0;
{
  RIAALockObject _(obj->mutex);
  cpyPtr = new ComplexObject(obj->org);
}
ComplexObject& cpy = *cpyPtr;  // create alias for ease of use.
```

Comment: You could use `boost::optional<ComplexObject>` instead if you wanted to avoid dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite unlikely that the default constructor would be avoided if the constructor is complex.

The compiler *can* do almost anything as long as the observable behaviour of your program remains intact.

The best way to solve this issue would be to not make the default constructor of `ComplexObject` expensive. It's bad practice to have expensive default constructors for this very reason.

Comment: I know that's the correct solution for this case, but I was hoping for a more general solution to wanting improper nesting of scoped objects.

Answer (score 3):

> Can (and do) C++ compilers replace the default construction/assignment of cpy with a copy constructor?

No, the compiler is forbidden from doing this (assuming that the default constructor of your class is complex enough that the compiler cannot prove that its elision will result in an equivalent program). Any compiler that does would not be standard conforming.

**EDIT: The following solution is flawed! Do not use it!**

*The following solution hides a race condition.* If your lock was to ensure that copying happened in a critical section then my “solution” will break this assumption since the copying may well (and probably will) happen *outside* this critical section. It *only* works if you are doing *other* work. But in your original code the mutex only makes sense if the copying itself is critical.

Just do the following to prevent default constructing:

```
ComplexObject = init(any_params_here);

ComplexObject init(any_params_here) {
    RAIILockObject _(obj->mutex);
    return obj->org;
}
```

Thanks to copy elision this won’t even perform unnecessary copies, just *one* (like in your code, but as a direct copy rather than copy assignment).

Comment: Also I’ve silently assumed that rather than the Recording Industry Association of America, you meant RAII.

Comment: The compiler is not forbidden from doing anything, as long as the observable behaviour remains the same: 1.9.1 "[...] conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine [...]". If default construction + assignment has the same behaviour as copy construction in this case then the compiler is free to replace them as it sees fit. Indeed, it often *will* do this.

Comment: @Peter, Now that he said it, I think I remember that Konrad is correct because the elision I'm asking for doesn't involve a temporarily object and I didn't restrict this to cases where the compiler would be assured of having access to the constructor or assignment functions.

Comment: @BCS: If that is the case then yes, it would be unlikely for that optimisation to occur, but still not impossible. Either way, it certainly doesn't break conformance to do it.

Comment: @Peter: agreed, but I want the require it.

Comment: @Peter I was operating on the premise that “the constructor … is costly”. Without strict aliasing rules it’s very quickly impossible for the compiler to prove that no other code depends on the initialisation of this local object. Does *any* current compiler do such an analysis?

Comment: @Konrad: You said the optimisation was forbidden, not difficult. Those are two completely different things. Also, since it's a local variable, as long as nothing takes the address of it, and its construction has no other side effects, then it's perfectly reasonable to expect a compiler to remove it. Whether it does in this case depends on exactly how complex the construction is.

Comment: @Peter That analysis is NP-hard. Of course this doesn’t necessarily mean that no compiler does it (everything is easy for a small problem size). That said, I usually stress correctness – I didn’t in this answer since my main emphasis was on the alternative solution, rather than eliciting whether the compiler could elide this construct. – Even if it could, my solution is still superior.